# unable to login with gmail

Tags: java, android, gmail

In my project I have integrated login using gmail. It is working fine but I have some issues. I have change the my computer and run the same project in that computer, but I am unable to login using gmail. Code below to understand the problem.

```java
private void signIn() {
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();


            healthPotliConstants.setFborgmaillogin("1");
            String g_email = acct.getEmail();
            String personName = acct.getDisplayName();



            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", email: " + g_email
            );



            checkIsRegistered(g_email, personName,"");

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please give Permission to login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use [Firebase-Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) which will let you authenticate users with one line of code?

Comment: Are you getting any error message in debug console?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your error.   Unable to login does not describe the issue.

Comment: handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result)  result is  blank after selecting email address for login

Comment: i am not getting any  debug message